# Ionic2 - Native Social Sharing Plugin Not Sharing Both Image and URL on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm working on a basic ionic2 application which requires social sharing.  I installed the cordova plugin per the ionic2 documentation and the documentation outlined in the repository (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin).  Please note that in the readme for the repository it does make a note that sharing both a link and an image will not work on Android.  This question is in regards to iOS.  I have been unable to share both the link and image via Facebook sharing.  All works well with sharing to all the other apps.  I have tried all the relevant methods: share(), shareWithOptions(), shareViaFacebook(), and shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint().  All result in the same behavior: I can share the link or the image, but not both at the same time.  Has anyone found a solution to this issue?  I updated my .plist file with the recommended entry just for good measure per the documentation.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Example of the rest of the code:

```
openShareMenu(){
 let shareOpts = {
   message: 'Hi',
   subject: 'Hello',
   url: 'https://google.com/',
   files: [this.example.imageURL]
 };
 //SocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(shareOpts.message,shareOpts.files[0],shareOpts.url);
 SocialSharing.shareWithOptions(shareOpts);
}
```

Thanks in advance.  I appreciate any help with this as it looks like others may have had similar issues, but there are no responses to the issues open in the repository.  Even a suggestion for a workaround would be appreciated.  I am on latest version of ionic2, social share plugin, and iOS.

Comment: did you figure it out!?

Comment: Hey @Abanoub I haven't worked with this plugin in a while, but I still see an open issue on Github that seems to be relevant: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/850.